How do I implement paginated queries in this code in PowerShell?
I have this code that uses the namespace System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.
However, the pagination I tried to implement is not working (only returns the first 500 items).
Could you tell me what is wrong?
$ldapFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(|(cn=CAX_*)(cn=F_*)(cn=G_*)))"
$results = @()
$pageSize = 500

try {
    # Conectar ao servidor LDAP
    Write-Host "Iniciando conexão com o servidor LDAP..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $ldapConnection = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection "ldap"
    $ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = $false
    $ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
    $ldapConnection.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Negotiate

    Write-Host "Conectando ao servidor LDAP..." -ForegroundColor Green

    # Configurar paginação
    Write-Host "Configurando controle de paginação com tamanho de página: $pageSize" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $pageControl = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.PageResultRequestControl($pageSize)
    $searchRequest = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest("DC=ldap,DC=com", $ldapFilter, "Subtree", "cn", "info", "description")
    $searchRequest.Controls.Add($pageControl)

    $morePages = $true

    while ($morePages) {
        # Enviar requisição de busca
        Write-Host "Enviando requisição de busca ao servidor LDAP..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $searchResponse = $ldapConnection.SendRequest($searchRequest)
        #Write-Host "Buscando grupos com o filtro: $ldapFilter" -ForegroundColor Green

        # Verificar resultados
        Write-Host "Processando resultados da página atual..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        foreach ($entry in $searchResponse.Entries) {
            Write-Host "Processando entrada: $($entry.Attributes["cn"][0])" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name        = $entry.Attributes["cn"][0]
                Info        = if ($entry.Attributes["info"].Count -gt 0) { $entry.Attributes["info"][0].Replace("r", "").Replace("n", "") -split "n" } else { "" }
                Description = if ($entry.Attributes["description"].Count -gt 0) { $entry.Attributes["description"][0] } else { "" }
            }
        }

        # Verificar se há mais páginas de resultados
        Write-Host "Verificando se há mais páginas de resultados..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $pageResponseControl = $searchResponse.Controls | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.PageResultResponseControl] }
        if ($pageResponseControl -and $pageResponseControl.Cookie.Length -gt 0) {
            Write-Host "Mais páginas encontradas, continuando a busca..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            $pageControl.Cookie = $pageResponseControl.Cookie
            $searchRequest.Controls.Clear()
            $searchRequest.Controls.Add($pageControl)  # Atualizar o controle de página na requisição de busca
        } else {
            Write-Host "Nenhuma outra página encontrada, finalizando busca." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            $morePages = $false
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Total de grupos encontrados: $($results.Count)" -ForegroundColor Green
} catch {
    Write-Host "Erro ao conectar ou buscar no LDAP: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
}

$adGroups = $results

# Se nenhum grupo foi encontrado, informe e saia do script
if ($adGroups.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Nenhum grupo encontrado. Verifique o filtro ou a conexão com o LDAP." -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

# Definir o caminho do arquivo JSON
$jsonPath = "C:\temp\GPAD\grupos_ad.json"
Write-Host "Exportando dados para o arquivo JSON em: $jsonPath" -ForegroundColor Cyan

# Exportar os dados para JSON
$adGroups | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $jsonPath -Encoding UTF8

Write-Host "Dados exportados para o arquivo JSON em: $jsonPath" -ForegroundColor Green

Output:

I want to get all the AD groups. It only brings 500 of them, but there is more than 1000 groups.
I appreciate your help!

Ensure you are using LDAP protocol version 3 that support pagination: $ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3

I edited the code with your suggestion. Unfortunately, nothing changed in the query returned.

Can you post the output you get when running the script?

Just posted the output.

@ThiagoLuan The screenshot you've posted shows a bunch of English-language messages, but the codes you've posted contains only sentences in Portuguese? Please make sure that the code you've posted here is actually the code you're debugging

I changed the messages language to make it easier for you guys. Its still the same script.

@ThiagoLuan Gotcha, thanks. In any case, the response either doesn't contain the paged control, or it's empty - try the suggestions here (namely adding either the SearchOptionsControl or disabling referral chasing)

@MathiasR.Jessen, that worked!!! Thank you so much. I will leave the code with the solution above.

@SantiagoSquarzon Sure.

As suggested in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols Paged get all users code suddenly stopped getting more than the first page of users, explicitly passing [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchOption]::DomainScope along with the search request might resolve whatever underlying issue occurs here.
using namespace System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

# ...
# construct the search request just like you currently are
$searchBaseDN = 'DC=ldap,DC=com'
$attributesToFetch = @(
  'cn'
  'info'
  'description'
)
$searchRequest = [SearchRequest]::new($searchBaseDN, $ldapFilter, "Subtree", $attributesToFetch)

# add the page control, same as now
$pageControl = [PageResultRequestControl]@{ PageSize = $pageSize }
[void]$searchRequest.Controls.Add($pageControl)

# ... and then additionally add an explicit search option control
$searchOptionsControl = [SearchOptionsControl]@{ SearchOption = 'DomainScope' }
[void]$searchRequest.Controls.Add($searchOptionsControl)

Note: I've rewritten the sample code slightly, taking advantage of the using namespace ... directive to shorten the type names. For PowerShell versions lower than 5.0 you would still need to use New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest ... instead of [SearchRequest]::new(...) for object instantiation.
